# XPages progressbar not working as expected with server page persistence setting "keep pages in memory"

Tags: javascript, dojo, xpages, lotus-domino

I would like to use Mark Leusnik's (thanks to him) really nice [ProgressBar](http://linqed.eu/2012/08/08/showing-real-progress-in-xpages/) implementation. Unfortunately the implementation doesn't work for me.

After some investigations, I found the reason for my troubles: In my xpage application, I have server page persistence setting `keep pages in memory`. In Mark Leusnik's [Demo App](http://vps-4562-5219.cloud.tilaa.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/progressBar.zip) the setting is `keep pages on disk`. I have no idea, why this setting has an impact on the runtime behavior of the progress bar?

**All works fine with setting `keep pages on disk`:**

---

[image]

**Unfortunately not with setting `keep pages in memory`:**

---

[image]

Thanks in advance for any solution, workaround or alternative!

Comment: I have found a workaround (xsp.session.transient=true) but not practicable for me, because I think that this setting has unexpected effects on my whole application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## WORKING SOLUTION (however other solutions, ideas, etc. for long running code progress bars are welcome)

After some further investigations, I have found a solution which works perfect independent of server page persistence settings (`keep pages in memory/ keep pages on disk`).

The key point of my solution is the implemention of an additional XAgent for the serverside task, instead of running the code inside the `onClick-Event` of the button. In addition, this XAgent will be "started" (`dojo.xhrGet`) in the start routine of the progress bar.

On Mark Leusnik's [solution](http://vps-4562-5219.cloud.tilaa.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/progressBar.zip) I have done the following changes:

---

**demo.xsp - XPage**

```
<xp:button value="Start a (fake) long running process" 
    id="button1" dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[xProgress.start();]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

**xProgress - Script Library (CSJS)**

```
start : function() {

    this.targetNode = dojo.byId(this.targetNodeId);

    if (this.targetNode==0) {
        alert("Invalid target node specified for xProgress progress bar");
    }

    //setup the dijit progressbar
    if (this.progressBar == null) {
        this.progressBar = new dijit.ProgressBar(
                {id: "myProgressBar", maximum: 100}, this.targetNode);
    } else {
        this.progressBar.update({
            maximum: 100,
            progress: 0
        });

    }

    dojo.xhrGet({
        url: window.location.href.substring(0, 
                    window.location.href.indexOf(".nsf")+4) + "/export.xsp",
        load: dojo.hitch(xProgress, "stop")
    });

    this.timerId = setInterval( dojo.hitch(xProgress, "update"), this.updateInterval);

},
```

**export.xsp - XAgent (the new one)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" rendered="false">

    <xp:this.afterRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript: print("long running code started");
    print( "browser: " + context.getUserAgent().getBrowser() + ", 
    remote IP: " + facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getRemoteAddr());

    updateProgress(0);

    /*java.lang.Thread.sleep(750);
    updateProgress(5);

    java.lang.Thread.sleep(750);
    updateProgress(10);

    java.lang.Thread.sleep(750);
    updateProgress(15);

    java.lang.Thread.sleep(750);
    updateProgress(20);

    java.lang.Thread.sleep(750);
    updateProgress(25);

    java.lang.Thread.sleep(750);
    updateProgress(30);

    java.lang.Thread.sleep(2000);
    updateProgress(50);

    java.lang.Thread.sleep(1500);
    updateProgress(60);

    java.lang.Thread.sleep(1500);
    updateProgress(75);

    java.lang.Thread.sleep(1500);
    updateProgress(80);

    java.lang.Thread.sleep(1500);
    updateProgress(90);

    java.lang.Thread.sleep(1500);
    updateProgress(100);*/

    print("long running code stopped");

    function updateProgress(to) {
        progressPercentage = to;
        synchronized(sessionScope) {
            sessionScope.put("progress", to);
        }
    }}]]></xp:this.afterRenderResponse>

</xp:view>
```